# How to copy values from one class type to the other class type in C#

Tags: c#

I am using fileHelpers to get data from text files. I have two text file types and therefor I created two classes:

```
    [DelimitedRecord("\t")]
    public sealed class dataFromFileType1
    {

        //Declare double type for wavelength
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public Double field1;

        //Declare double type for reflectance
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public Double field2;

    }

    [DelimitedRecord(",")]
    public sealed class dataFromFileType2
    {

        //Declare double type for wavelength
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public Double field1;

        //Declare double type for reflectance
        [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
        public Double field2;

    }
```

Finally, I want to convert the two class types into one unified class type, so that I can use one method to process both data. I defined:

```
    public sealed class unifiedData
    {

        public Double field1;
        public Double field2;

    }
```

The question is how to copy (or convert) the object arrays of class dataFromFileType1 and class dataFromFileType2 to the object arrays of class unifiedData?

Comment: What's the rule to unify them? Like Concat? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could use for example AutoMapper: 
https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

```
Mapper.CreateMap<dataFromFileType1, unifiedData>();
Mapper.CreateMap<dataFromFileType2, unifiedData>();
```